# Image not stretching to 100 % HTML

Tags: html, css

I had an image

```
<img src="bg.png" style="width:100%; height:100%"/>
```

But it leaves some border on all 4 sides of the page. A background image does not do so.

I do not want that border. Please help.

Comment: provide us your code that contains the image

Comment: try to add to the style border: none;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default browsers put 8px margin on 4 sides defined by *user-agent-stylesheet*. You can override by adding style to the body.

```
<body style="margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 0px">
```

In this case, you can have full image!

Comment: Thanks a ton mate :)

Answer (score 2):

> In most major browsers, the default margin is 8px on all sides. It is
>   defined in pixels by the user-agent-stylesheet your browser provides.
>
> Some browsers allow you to create and use your own
>   user-agent-stylesheet, but if you are developing a website, I would
>   recommend staying away from changing this, since your users most
>   likely will not have a modified stylesheet and would then see a
>   different page than you do.

So, You can **Reset/Normalize** your css by adding this code to CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

But if you have a large project and want to be more complete, use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/). It resets a lot of default values to be consistent across browsers. Good Luck ^_^